why global value picklist enabled check box sort alphabetically by default after deployment?
requirement is we need to arrange value in particular order
but even we unchecked checkbox of 'sort alphabetical' value are sorting after deploy .
please help with your valuable answers .
Thanks in advance
i tried by uncheck check box and deploy that time it looks fine but after some  deployment it remains same behavior

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
